# _csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem with the csv module in python.

This is the code I've written to parse my csv

```
def parse(data):
    data_delim = data.split("\n")
    data_list = csv.reader(data_delim)
    return data_list
```

The problem I am encountering is the following:

```
print(data_list[Enum.check_name(skill)][1])
```

Throws this error

```
_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

I have a ghetto solution for this below, but I'd rather use something similar to the code above, does anyone have a solution to this?

```
i = 0
for a in data_list:
    if i == Enum.check_name(skill):
        print(a[1])
    i += 1
```

Comment: What do you intend `data_list[Enum.check_name(skill)]` to do?  You can't use indexing to say "get the row with this value in the first column".

Comment: I was intending it the get the value at index Enum.check_name(skill), for example I would compare it to writing data_list[1][1] to get the value of the second row in the second column.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As the error message says, csv readers don't support indexing.  The value returned by `csv.reader` is not a list; it's an iterator over the rows.

If you want, you could make a list of all the rows with `data_list = list(csv.reader(data_delim))`.  Then you can index that list as you would any other.